# Как запретить ручное скачивание файла из <audio>

Tags: php, html5, файлы, .htaccess, apache

На сайте размещены аудио файлы в закрытой директории через .htaccess, однако из-за использования `<audio controls controlsList="nodownload" srs="...mp3">` опытный юзер, все же, может скачать файл, убрав `nodownload` из кода страницы, тем самым открыв кнопку "Скачать" в некоторых браузерах

При запрете загрузки через .htaccess `deny from all` плеер тоже не может использовать файл.

Если ставлю проверку на предыдущую страницу тоже

Каким образом нужно изменить правило или как я могу запретить ручное скачивание данных файлов, или есть какието другие методы защиты файлов

PS: кнопка chrome отключена `nodownload`
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но если убрать строчку из кода страницы, появляется три точки и скачать
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так чтобы проиграть ваш mp3, его сперва надо скачать... или как вы хотите? мол музыку каким-то чудом проиграй, но скачку запрети?

Comment: Чтобы браузер при загрузке страницы скачал во временную папку-или как там, но если человек нажимает "скачать" - загрузка блокируется

Comment: Ключевая проблема что юзер может в один клик стереть `nodownload` в коде и появляется замечательная кнопочка "скачать", и у меня не получается ни её вытравить, ни запретить "ручную" загрузку

Comment: Можно скачать поток который воспроизводится

Comment: Да, но это совсем другой уровень прямоты рук. В chrome есть тупо кнопка скачать, и с ней проблема

Comment: Walker, подскажите, как вы справились с этой задачей. Очень нужно...

Comment: @Сергей Я использовал метод Рустама и в добавок отключил контекстное меню скриптом написаны под его ответом. Метод неидеален, но требует куда более прямых рук чтобы заполучить аудио или видео

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Сделайте мало мальский кастомный проигрыватель.
- Либо установите наблюдателя за изменением атрибута, если уж так надо.

```js
var element = document.querySelector('audio');

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    if ('attributes' === mutation.type &&
      'controlslist' === mutation.attributeName &&
      !element.getAttribute('controlslist')
    ) {
      alert('Попытка изменить атрибут "controlslist"');
      element.setAttribute('controlslist', 'nodownload');
    }
  });
});

observer.observe(element, {
  attributes: true
});

setTimeout(function() {
  element.setAttribute('controlslist', '');
}, 2000)
```

```html
<audio controls controlslist="nodownload" src="https://img.imgsmail.ru/static.promo/sounds/notifier/bell.mp3">
    Your browser does not support the<code>audio</code> element.
</audio>
```

---

**NB** Правой кнопкой мыши на стандартном проигрывателе в Chrome, там есть пункт `Сохранить аудио как ...`.

**NB** Скачивать можно умудриться, даже с тех сайтов где на `.ts` фрагменты поделено.

Comment: Для последователей: отличный метод и в добавок нужно отключить контекстное меню чтобы нельзябыло открыть в другой вкладке `$('audio').bind('contextmenu', function(e) {
    return false;
});`

Comment: СпасиБо!! это просто супер! вставила на сайт, все работает! Огромное спасибо, что не бросаете в трудную минуту и можно найти информацию!!!!!!